# Segmenting characters from a license plate with OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I cleaned a patent plate to read the characters. Now, I am stuck in a part where I must segment the characters.

For the phase of cleaning the plate I do this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Now the idea is to be able to segment the characters and then be able to read it with a neural network that I developed, For segmentation I carry this but still don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
# Create sort_contours() function to grab the contour of each digit from left to right
def sort_contours(cnts,reverse = False):
    i = 0
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
                                        key=lambda b: b[1][i], reverse=reverse))
    return cnts

cont, _  = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# creat a copy version "test_roi" of plat_image to draw bounding box
test_roi = plate_image.copy()

# Initialize a list which will be used to append charater image
crop_characters = []

# define standard width and height of character
digit_w, digit_h = 40, 80

for c in sort_contours(cont):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ratio = h/w
    if 1<=ratio<=3.5: # Only select contour with defined ratio
        if h/plate_image.shape[0]>=0.1: # Select contour which has the height larger than 50% of the plate
            # Draw bounding box arroung digit number
            cv2.rectangle(test_roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255,0), 2)

            # Sperate number and gibe prediction
            curr_num = thre_mor[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            curr_num = cv2.resize(curr_num, dsize=(digit_w, digit_h))
            _, curr_num = cv2.threshold(curr_num, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
            crop_characters.append(curr_num)

print("Detect {} letters...".format(len(crop_characters)))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.axis(False)
plt.imshow(test_roi)
```

How could I make the implementation correct? Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to label them by a neural network the first step of cleaning up is not needed. If you look it to region propose neural network (rnn, fast-rnn, faster-rnn, yolo, mask-rnn ect.) they will do the segmentation and classification in one go.

If you do want to go for segmentation first look in to connected components. It will select all the positive pixels what are connected together.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, previously I used YOLO to detect and segment characters but it did not give good results, for the scope of what I am doing, it seems fine to use filters and masks.

Comment: How did it preform on the training and validation/developers set?